# How to use play-slick with H2 and MySQL compatibility mode in dev, and MySQL in production?

Tags: playframework, slick, play-slick

I’ve started using [play-slick](https://github.com/freekh/play-slick) and would like to know if the following is possible. In development I want to use H2 in MySQL compatibility mode, and in production use MySQL.

However, I think this isn’t working for me in development because play-slick uses the Slick driver based on the currently configured database. This is H2, so slick generates H2-style SQL, which fails in MySQL compatibility mode because the quoting for attribute and table names is different.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICS Slick doesn't have any H2 MySql compatibility mode support in its driver, so it will be hard to get play-slick to use it. 
Maybe this is a silly question but the way I see it you are using H2 instead of Mysql in dev mode either way, so why do you want it to be in MySql compatibility mode?